# SETEX error - "Use of closed network connection"

Tags: go, redis

I'm using the following code to execute a SET and EXPIRE from my Go app.

```
_, err = C.Cache.Do("SETEX", key, 3600, data)
```

but I've started to get an error: **Use of closed network connection**. I use Gary Burd's [Redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) package and RedisLabs.

My code to connect to Redis is:

```
//Connect to cache (Redis)
cache, err := connectToCache()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Cache connection settings are invalid")
    os.Exit(1)
}
defer cache.Close()

func connectToCache() (redis.Conn, error) {
    cache, err := redis.Dial("tcp", CACHE_URI)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = cache.Do("AUTH", CACHE_AUTH)
    if err != nil {
        cache.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    return cache, nil
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error about a closed connection, you need to reconnect to the DB. Shouldn't have anything to do with the SETEX command (which by the way is superseded in newer versions by using SET with options)

Comment: I've added my code to show how I manage the Redis connection - are there any obvious issues with it at all? Thanks for the info on the SET (with options) command.

Comment: I can't tell from the code out of context where the defer will happen, but you should keep connections around and reuse them whenever possible. Usually you want a [`redis.Pool`](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool). See my answer here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244080/sharing-redis-settings-across-routes/30244721#30244721

Comment: Great - I wasn't sure when i would need a pool but I guess it's now.

Comment: If @JimB's answer does not work, then run the application with the [race detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector) and read the Redigo documentation [regarding concurrency](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Concurrency).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [`redis.Pool`](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool) to manage multiple connections, check that idle connections are alive, and get new connections automatically. You can also do the AUTH step automatically when dialing a new connection:

```
func newPool(server, password string) *redis.Pool {
    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle: 3,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial: func () (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", server)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if _, err := c.Do("AUTH", password); err != nil {
                c.Close()
                return nil, err
            }
            return c, err
        },
        TestOnBorrow: func(c redis.Conn, t time.Time) error {
            _, err := c.Do("PING")
            return err
        },
    }
}

var (
    pool *redis.Pool
    redisServer = flag.String("redisServer", ":6379", "")
    redisPassword = flag.String("redisPassword", "", "")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    pool = newPool(*redisServer, *redisPassword)
    ...
}
```

Comment: So as you pointed out in the other answer I just use something like `conn = pool.Get()` each time I need a new connection?

Comment: @tommyd456: yes, every time you need a connection you call `pool.Get()`, and then call `conn.Close` to return the connection to the pool.

Comment: I assume it's prefable to defer the close operation

Comment: And also, as this is an API I'm making - would I create the connection each time a route is hit just before the Redis operation itself?

Comment: @tommyd456: yes, you need to ensure you call Close, or the connection won't go back into the pool. You get a connection from the pool when you need a connection, and return it when you're done.