# redis crashes when angular send request

Tags: angular, linux, sockets, go

I have a go server with redigo and I have this function to get data from redis :

```
func findCompetition(conn redis.Conn, username string) competition{
    conn.Send("KEYS", "*")
    conn.Flush()
    re, erre := conn.Receive()
    keys, err := redis.Strings(re, erre)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(re)
        log.Print(err)
        return competition{Username:"null"}
    }
    for _, key := range keys {
        comp := getCompetition(conn, key)
        if comp.Competitor == username && 
time.Now().Sub(comp.Time_asked).Minutes() < 2.0 {
            return comp
        }
    }
    return competition{Username:"null"}
}
```

when I send request by browser like : http://localhost:4500/find_competition/aicam
It's ok but when my angular project send request every 1.5sec after some seconds log.Print(err) prints error below :

read tcp 127.0.0.1:35874->127.0.0.1:6379: use of closed network connection

I tried all of the solutions like : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180858/setex-error-use-of-closed-network-connection) [github](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/issues/31)
and port 35874 changes sometimes

Comment: Thanks Cerise , I replaced but it throws error again.
when I use lsof -i :6379 it returns go project that is connected to , but after crash it shows nothing

Comment: I heard that I can write a function to check the connection and make connection if it closed. have you seen such function?

Comment: Thanks Cerise , I tried it. I found out when the connection closes , if I run project again it doesn't make new connection to redis server until 5 or 6 minutes.What is going on? :(((

Comment: this is the complete project https://dev.azure.com/alirisheh876/chatroom-service/_git/game_server
Thanks a lot Mr.Cerise , in routhandler redisFunc is redis functions

Comment: Run the application with the race detector and fix any errors.  Follow the pool [documentation's](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Pool) advice for web applications.